# Create edgelist from dataframe depending on groups and time period

Tags: r, igraph, reshape, network-analysis

I am trying to create an edge list from a data frame that is depending on two things: (1) belonging to the same group (2) during the same time period. One person may belong to multiple groups at once.

```
# read example vectors
ppl <- c("pers1", "pers2","pers3","pers4","pers5","pers2","pers6","pers1")
grp <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
timeST <- c(2005,2005,2010,2012,2014,2007,2008,2008)
timeTER <- c(2010,2007,2018,2014,2015,2010,2020,2020)
# construct example data frame
example.df <- data.frame(ppl, grp, timeST, timeTER)
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
#create edge list by groups:
target.df <- example.df %>% select(ppl, grp, timeST, timeTER) %>%
inner_join(., select(., grp, ppl), by = "grp") %>%
rename(ppl1 = ppl.x, ppl2 = ppl.y) %>%
filter(ppl1 != ppl2) %>%
unique %>%
arrange(grp)
target.df <- target.df[, c("ppl1","ppl2","grp","timeST","timeTER")]
# display results:
target.df
```

However, I am at a loss on how to divide this into multiple years, as in: There should only be an edge between two persons, when persX and persY have been in the same group at the same time. I assume the data needs to be put into long format, so I tried working with reshape and reshape2, but can not get it to reflect the time period.

Ideally, I would create one edge list per year, which I would then transform into and adjacency matrix (this is no problem by itself). This issue is further complicated by the fact that every person needs to be in every adjacency matrix, so if pers4 is not present past 2011, it would still need to appear in the matrix, but get the value 10 for each row/column instead of a 0 or 1.. but I wanted to take it one step at a time.

This would look something like this:

```
ex.M <- matrix(c(0,1,0,10,1,0,0,10,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10), nrow=4, ncol=4)
ex.M
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun problem, even though the solution is more about managing your data than it is about igraph as such. Within each group, you're loking to list the persons who overlap in time.

We'd need a good method for evaluating the overlaps.

This is not the nicest solution (a hack with the result-format of the overlap-function makes it inposible to use the year 0), but at least it's pedagogical.

```
library('dplyr')

ppl <- c("pers1", "pers2","pers3","pers4","pers5","pers2","pers6","pers1")
grp <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
timeST <- c(2005,2005,2010,2012,2014,2007,2008,2008)
timeTER <- c(2010,2007,2018,2014,2015,2010,2020,2020)
# construct example data frame
example.df <- data.frame(ppl, grp, timeST, timeTER)

# Just like in your logic, these are peple that overlap within the same group.
df <- example.df %>% inner_join(example.df, by="grp")


# We get a structure with the start and end times for both i and j like:
names(df)



# This function is used to compute overlapping years between the intervals
# that exist between timeST.x-timeTER.x and "timeST.y-timeTER.y

time.period.overlap <- function(x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end)
{
    # Return intersections of time-periods (x_start - x_end) and (y_start - y_end)
    x <- seq(x_start, x_end)
    y <- seq(y_start, y_end)
    
    # Each result contains at least a row of 0 to stay true to the data-format and avoid NULLs
    c(unique( c(x[x %in% y], y[y %in% x]) ),  0)
}



# Make an edge-list of person-to-person WITHIN grp and WITH overlapping years
# as defined by time.period.overlap(). Choose only rows that DO HAVE an overlap
all.edges <-
    do.call('rbind',
            lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x)
                data.frame(
                    i = df[x, 'ppl.x'],
                    j = df[x, 'ppl.y'],
                    grp = df[x, 'grp'],
                    yr_overlap = time.period.overlap(df[x, 'timeST.x'], df[x, 'timeTER.x'], df[x, 'timeST.y'], df[x, 'timeTER.y'])
                )
            )
    ) %>% filter(yr_overlap != 0)

# Note that pairs like edges like pers4->pers2 in group 2 are not in this df
# since they never appeared in that group during the same year!
all.edges[all.edges$i == 'pers4',]
# For each pair i->j within each group, one row exists for each overlapping year

# Group by i, j and group to find the number of years of each pair's overlap to use in the network
el <- all.edges %>% group_by(i, j, grp) %>% summarise(n_yr_overlap = n(), first_overlap = min(yr_overlap))
```

Now the edge-list el can be sent to igraph for an aggregate network, or you could subsample networks for each given year using the `all.edges`.

Remember to handle self-loops (either in the data-frames or when creating your iGraph object) according to if it is logical that people have edges to themselves or not (which they do have in this output).

Comment: For some reason I did not receive a notification on this, so apologies for the late response. This works just great and the code is written in a way that makes it very easy for me to understand what's going on. Very pedagogical indeed - Thank you!